# PostGIS Raster - geocoordinates - where is pixel center

Tags: postgis, raster

I am using PostGIS raster to store geographical data - usually height maps. I wonder, how is raster represented. Where is pixel center?

For example, I create raster with upper left corner `[lat: 50, lon: 40]` and scale set to `1`. Is this upper left corner coordinate meant as a center of pixel (*red color*) or really an upper left corner (*green color*)?

If I later read from DB and request value at `[lat: 49.9, lon: 39.9]`, will I get the value of pixel with *red center* or some neighbour?

[image]

Comment: You can test it yourself with https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsPoint.html and https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsCentroid.html.

Comment: @user30184 It solves the first part of question. And as for ST_Value, it returns value based on red or green point?

Comment: Test yourself with QGIS or OpenJump...